# Display another jsp content in current jsp page upon a hyperlink click

Tags: html, jsp-tags

I am developing a web based application in which i have two hyperlinks in the left side of the page, and what i'm looking for is that when i click on the one hyperlink it should load the content of another.jsp and display it over present.jsp and if I click next hyperlink it should do the same for third.jsp over present.jsp .

I found something on stackoverflow like:-

javascript--

```
    function showItem(url) {
$('#right-pane').load(url);
```

}

link--< a href="showItem('another.jsp)">item 1

where "right-pane" is the id of div tag where i want the another jsp content to be displayed.

```
< div id="right-pane" style="position: absolute; width: 988px; height: 649px; z-index: 2; left: 193px; top: 4px">

< /div>
```

But when i am clicking on **item 1** its saying-- The requested resource (/test1/showItem('another.jsp')) is not available.

I am using apache tomcat as a server.

Thanks,
Arshad

Comment: have you included Jquery.js if not check out http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: Hi Kim, Yes i have added like:-

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showItem(url) {
$('#right-pane').load(url);

 }

        </script>

in head region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a class or id t your link

```
 < a href="'another.jsp" class="link1">item 1</a>
```

Add this to your header:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".link1").click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       var url =$(this).attr("href");
       $('#right-pane').load(url);
    });
});
```

try change this`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">` line to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**tryed and tested this in ie9:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>title</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".link1").click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       var url =$(this).attr("href");

        $('#right-pane').load(url, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
       console.log(url);
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="layer5" class="style2" style="position: absolute; width: 79px; height: 17px; z-index: 1; left: 11px; top: 15px"><a href="test2.html" class="link1">item 1</a></div> 
        <div id="right-pane" style="position: absolute; width: 988px; height: 649px; z-index: 2; left: 193px; top: 4px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi Kim, thanks for the code but whenever i'm clicking on the hyperlink its not opening in the div section of my current page, Its opening the page "another.jsp" itself.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
        $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".link1").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var url =$(this).attr("href");
        $('#right-pane').load(url);
     });});</script>
</head><body>
<div id="layer5" class="style2" style="position: absolute; width: 79px; height: 17px; z-index: 1; left: 11px; top: 15px"><a href="another.jsp" class="link1">item 1</a></div>
<div id="right-pane" style="position: absolute; width: 988px; height: 649px; z-index: 2; left: 193px; top: 4px"></div>

Comment: @Kim-- Thanks very much Kim, superlike. you saved my lot of time. thanks very much for favor. :)

Comment: Hi Kim, I have one issue regarding the above solution i.e. when after clicking over third.jsp its showing the page but when again I switch back to another.jsp by clicking over the left menu containing the hyperlink, Its showing the blank (another.jsp), I am loosing all the previous data.
Please help.

Comment: Hi Kim, Please update me with some solution, I got stuck here and its quite serious. help please.