# Displaying streams in DIV

Tags: java, javascript, html

I am running some terminal(or command prompt) commands through my servlet as below

```
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
   {
    String[] command =
        {
      "zsh"
          };
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), response.getOutputStream())).start();
                new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream())).start();
                PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
                stdin.println("source ./taxenv/bin/activate");
                stdin.println("python runner.py");
                stdin.close();
                int returnCode = 0;
                try {
                    returnCode = p.waitFor();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } System.out.println("Return code = " + returnCode);
    }
    class SyncPipe implements Runnable
    {
    public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
          istrm_ = istrm;
          ostrm_ = ostrm;
      }
      public void run() {
          try
          {
              final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
              for (int length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1; )
              {
                  ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);
              }
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
      private final OutputStream ostrm_;
      private final InputStream istrm_;
    }
```

This is displaying the result after executing terminal commands in a new window, I want to avoid that and pass these stream values back to JSP page and display the same in a div.

How to do that?

Comment: Instead of `void`, pass back values and read them in with JSP?

Comment: Instead of 'ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);' I want to send them back to JSP

Comment: So you advice me to put up all this stuff into <% %> and import things ?? I'll try this out and will update you.

Comment: It depends on your application. Please refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Static import

First of all, you can define a `scriplet` with `<%=` and `%>` like [explained here](http://www.jsptut.com/Scriptlets.jsp) and [here](http://www.jsptut.com/Mixing.jsp).

Instead of copying the whole code, you can statically import the `.jsp` page like so:

```
<%@ include file="YourPage.jsp" %>
```

> [Link](http://www.jsptut.com/Directives.jsp).

To call the page at runtime instead of at the server-side you do:

```
<jsp:include page="YourPage.jsp"/>
```

But this doesn't yield a huge advantage over static importing.

> [Link](http://www.jsptut.com/Tags.jsp)

You can also declare your function and then use it throughout your webpage by using `<%!` and `%>` like [shown here](http://www.jsptut.com/Declarations.jsp).

If you do any of the methods above, your function will (can) be imported  only when the page initially loads (server-side). (To be absolutely correct, `<jsp:include` is called at runtime in theory but in practice it simulates a request *without* actually making a complete round-trip: `server > browser > server > browser`).

### Dynamic import

For dynamic importing or loading, you have to resort to jQuery (JavaScript) to load your JSP page client-side.

Please refer to this question: [How do I inject another JSP page into a <div> when clicking a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335547/how-do-i-inject-another-jsp-page-into-a-div-when-clicking-a-link/12335610#12335610)

You could simply do:

```
function changeContent() {
    $('#content').load('YourPage.jsp');
}
```

You can find other examples here:

> - [Display another jsp content in current jsp page upon a hyperlink click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719222/display-another-jsp-content-in-current-jsp-page-upon-a-hyperlink-click)
> - [CodeRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/291029/JSP/java/Displaying-JSP-DIV-tag)

To quote the answer from the last link:

That's something to do with Ajax, Jquery can do that. **You can use javascript** `getElementByID` **or use Jquery's build_in** `$("sub_banner")` **syntax to change the div's content**.

Comment: @Zedai: Sure no problem. I hope it helps you out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer was very helpful and en-lighting. Thank you!